# Alternatives to geom_segment for plotting point ranges in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting a map of VHF receiver locations. For each receiver location, I would like to add estimated detection ranges (12km in line-of-sight) of the antennas attached to each receiver.

I have been able to do this using geom_segment shown below:

[image]
But I'd like to more accurately represent the antenna detection ranges with balloons instead of line segments (example pic below)

[image: Map of Receiver Locations with desired detection ranges]

Here is my current code to reproduce the line segment approach:

```
   library(ggmap);library(ggplot2)

   tower <- data.frame(id="somewhere", lat = 29.5634, lon = -82.6111)

    map1 <- get_map(location = tower[,c("lon","lat")], maptype = "satellite", zoom=9)  

    tower$start = tower$lon - 0.2 # creates segment length of approx 12km in degrees
    tower$end = tower$lon + 0.2 # creates segment length of approx

    ggmap(map1) +  geom_segment(data=tower, aes(x=tower$start, 
                             y=tower$lat, 
                             xend=tower$end, 
                             yend=tower$lat), 
                             size=1, colour="red") + 
                    geom_point(data=tower, aes(x=lon, y=lat), colour="black")
```

Any suggestions on how to recreate the example figure would be appreciated.

Thanks
Bryant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit verbose, but we can add four `geom_curve` to create that shape.

Note the `coord_cartesian()` at the end, `geom_curve is not implemented for non-linear coordinates` so we force the coord to be cartesian. This means that this method is only applicable on a small scale.

```
ggmap(map1) + 
  # geom_segment(data = tower,
  #              aes(x = start,
  #                  y = lat,
  #                  xend = end,
  #                  yend = lat),
  #              size = 1, colour = "red") +
  geom_curve(data = tower, 
             aes(x = lon, 
                 y = lat, 
                 xend = I(lon - .2), 
             curvature = -.5,
             angle = 45,color = 'yellow') +
  geom_curve(data = tower, 
             aes(x = lon, 
                 y = lat, 
                 xend = end, 
                 yend = lat),
             curvature = .5,
             angle = 135,color = 'yellow') +
  geom_curve(data = tower,
             aes(x = lon,
                 y = lat,
                 xend = start,
                 yend = lat),
             curvature = .5,
             angle = 135,color = 'yellow') +
  geom_curve(data = tower,
             aes(x = lon,
                 y = lat,
                 xend = end,
                 yend = lat),
             curvature = -.5,
             angle = 45,color = 'yellow') +
  geom_point(data = tower, aes(x = lon, y = lat), colour = "black") +
  coord_cartesian()
```

[image]

I guess alternatively a new `geom_*` could be created.

Comment: Yes, thank you! This should work. Interesting solution. Ill need to look into potentially creating a new geom for generalization of this task (and for it to work at bigger scales).